# What are the different types of circular buttons in material design?(other than floating action button)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

The default lollipop apps(like dialer in motoG) has some rounded iconic buttons in the LISTVIEWS and also the TOOLBAR, please refer the screenshot 
[image: The red circles 1,2,3 are rounded buttons I am talking about]
Please tell me what are these buttons as per my understanding 2,3 are TOOLBAR(actionbar) icons and I assume 1 button is the floating action button.

Please share a sample code to create a button like the ones in the image especially the 1st button.

Answer (score 2):

That button is pretty straight forward. Using the AppCompat library lets you use `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` as a background, which achieves the desired effect.

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: 1.Can we use appcompat for lollipop also?
2.Will I get a rounded button like in the image?

Comment: Yeah, in fact, you should just be using AppCompat anyway -- if Google find a bug they can update the library right away (rather than being stuck with it for that api level)

Answer (score -3):

This is a fab button.

Include Angular Material in your project then use the following code to create a 'Comment' fab button.

```
<md-button class="md-fab" aria-label="Comment">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_comment_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```